# Advice on working with Palettes needed

Tags: notebooks, palettes

I'm dealing with several projects and would like to keep track of my work and notes into a notebook per project. Each notebook should have a top cell with basic information like:

Customer name
Internal references
People working on project

It's easy to create a palette with a button to launch a `CreateDialog`, input all the information and write it to a notebook. However what if I want to change that information; e.g., add a reference.

I presume that I would need to create a unique variable for each notebook that I can lookup for (by using tags?) and change accordingly. Information already present can be shown in the `CreateDialog` expression and stuff can be changed or added.

Before starting to work on this I would to get advice on whether or not this is a good approach.

Tips and trick, pitfalls and pointers to good documentation would also be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that should fit your needs, you can set this for any project notebook you meant:

```
dockedCellTemplate = Grid[{
     {"project:", Lookup[#, "name", "---"]},
     {"link:", Hyperlink @  Lookup[#, "link", "---"]}
   }, Alignment -> Left
] &;


dockedCell = With[{template = dockedCellTemplate}
  , Cell @ BoxData @ ToBoxes @ Dynamic[template[ 
       CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "metadata"}
       ] /.  Inherited -> {}
]]]

SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],  DockedCells -> {dockedCell}  ]

CurrentValue[ EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "metadata"}
] = {"name" -> "MyProject", "link" -> "https://mathematica.stackexchange.com"}
```

Now, whenever you update/change `TaggingRules` it should be reflected in the docked cell.

The template was injected with `With` so you have to redo all that if you want to change it. Or you could not inject it but then you'd have to care about loading the definition in case of kernel restart etc. Up to you at the end.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Kuba, Thanks for this example. I'll start working with this. I noticed that when I print the notebook (to PDF) the docked cell is not printed. Any idea how this can be included in the PDF? Thx!

Comment: I do not do much printing but I'm not surprised. Where would it be?, it is always on top wherever you scroll.